# applicationinsights clickanalytics.js npm - add custom property

Tags: azure, npm, azure-application-insights, user-tracking

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/applicationinsights-clickanalytics-js to send click event as telemetry data to application insights.

What I need to do is to send for all the events a custom propery - for example a tenant id - that I can use in the provided visualizations/queries to do group bys.

[image]

Honestly I do not find a way on how to do this.
I found there are possiblities to use a `TelemetryProcessor` or something like

```
appInsights.defaultClient.commonProperties = {
   environment: process.env.SOME_ENV_VARIABLE
};
```

But I find no way on how to achive this with the npm package.

Any hints, idea?
Basically I want to add a custom property that is written with every autogenerated or manual event.

Answer (score 0):

For future generations stuck with the same issue ;)

I solved it like this

```
  const telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
                const user = getUserFromSomewhere();
                if (!user) {
                    console.log("User is not set")
                    return false;
                }
                envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = user?.tenant;
                return true;
            };
            appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: may i ask what part you find unclear?